# How can I prefix links in my Rails views based on a condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have some existing routes like:

```
/people/:id
/events/:id
```

and so on, in my `routes.rb`.

Now I want to provide custom styling for my affiliate customers. My current thinking is that my routes will look like:

```
/people/:id
/events/:id
...

/affiliates/:id/people/:id
/affiliates/:id/events/:id
...
```

and so on.

However, I want to make sure that **the links I generate in my views will always get prefixed with `/affiliates/:id` if I'm on an affiliate pages**. (I don't want to have to write an "is this an affiliate?" conditional every time I use a `url_for` or `path_for` helper.)

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In my option it is better if you handle that logic inside the controller rather than in the view.

You can have something as follows:

```
class EventController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    if(current_user.is_affiliate?)
      #render the affiliate view
    else
      #renders regular view
    end
  end
```

In your view you can simply have

```
<%= link_to "Event", @event %>
```

So that the view doesn't need to manage that logic and you can keep it on the controller.